# How to get integer data from a text file as a Javascript Variable?

Tags: javascript, php

I've found a php script to count my sites downloads. It saves downloads counts in a txt file as integer type. Like the count.txt contains only "109", means file was downloaded 109 times. I want to show the download counts using native javascript. Not PHP. just want to get the integer data from the txt file as variable. Is it posssible? if possible, how?

PHP Script is:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=1.jpeg">
</head>
<body>

<?php

$fp = fopen("Count.txt", "r");
$count = fread($fp, 1024);
fclose($fp);
$count = $count + 1;
$fp = fopen("Count.txt", "w");
fwrite($fp, $count);
fclose($fp);

?> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that. From security reasons JavaScript is not allowed to read data from files that are saved on the system. Why not try modifying the script to use localStorage for saving count, that you can read very easily latter.

Comment: onetwo12 is correct.  You can't do that PHP is a server side language an JavaScript is a client side language.  If you want to show the download counts you would either need to find or write a PHP script that would increment a database table or write a PHP script that would read the file and output the result.  You already have most of what you need to write it.

Comment: You could do a XHR request to get the .txt if it can be accessed by the URL,  otherwise it's what @onetwo12 said.

Comment: thanks, i did it at last

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used This JS for XmlHttpRequest to get the variable from count.txt

```
<h1>Downloaded <span id="displaydlcount"></span> Times!

<script type="text/javascript">
     function lol(){
      var read = new XMLHttpRequest();
      read.open('GET', 'Count.txt', false);
      read.send();
      var displayName = parseInt(read.responseText)
      document.getElementById("displaydlcount").innerHTML = displayName;
      setTimeout("lol()",1000)
      }
      window.onload = lol();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using AJAX. Assuming the txt file is in the same directory as the file that runs the script, you should be able to use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "Count.txt",
            success: function (dataString){
                console.log(dataString);
            }
        });
})
```

*Note: This doesn't seem to work on localhost, but I tested it on my server and it worked.*

Comment: Thanks, I've used XMLhttpRequest TO get the integer data.

Comment: Glad you got it to work. Under the hood, it's the same thing, just that jquery's version of ajax has a "friendlier" syntax.